# What does inequality look like when measured in man-hours employed?

Tags: united-states, economy, income, inequality

There are numerous measures of inequality in income and wealth, like the [Gini coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient) for instance.  But I'm wondering about a different measure: the amount of labor, measured in man-hours, that is employed in the production of the goods and services that a given person consumes.  Inequality of man-hours employed was clearly quite high in the United States in the early twentieth century, since rich people back then had servants, cooks, drivers, and the like, and they owned a lot of labor-intensive luxury goods.  So I'm wondering what that measure of inequality looks like in the US today and in the recent past, and how it compares with the rest of the world.

Note that this isn't some metric I'm making up out of whole cloth; I think back in 2007 or so the New York Times ran a series of articles on class differences in modern America, and they said that one of the best indicators of someone's economic class is whether they have goods and services that took a lot of labor to make, or whether their daily life doesn't command a lot of human resources.  And I think they said that judged in this way, class is more prevalent in American society than it might otherwise seem.  So I'm pretty sure there's plenty out of data out there on this measure.

Comment: "amount of man-hours employed in the production of goods consumed" So, a person with a private tutor that puts in fewer hoursis less wealthy  than a a person who goes to public school that has multiple teachers/administrators/etc.  racking up hours. Same could be said for a personal chef. How do we measure things produced by machines? (every engineer that designed the machine, the maintanence, etc.)

Comment: @user1873 As far as machines go, the relevant metric would be marginal cost, not total cost.  So yes, there might have been labor that went into building the machine and the like, but what we're talking about the labor that was involved in making the additional unit.

Comment: @user1873 And no, I wouldn't include the labor of administrators and the labor of other teachers in the school, just the labor of the teachers that directly teach the student.  Although teaching is an exceptional case, because a teacher is teaching multiple students at once, so it would be hard to count how much labor goes into servicing a particular student.

Comment: @user1873 In any case, as I said this isn't some metric that I'm making up; there's already been data that's been collected for this metric, so if someone's able to answer this question we can see exactly how the man-hours have been counted.

Comment: @user1873 - I would say that for teachers and other "group" situations, the teacher's time is divided by all students.  So a 45 minute class(.75 hours) for 20 students accrues 0.0375 man-hours for each student.  You could count administrator time this way too but spread across all students in the school it would be pretty minimal.  This accounts for larger class sizes (i.e. worse student:teacher ratios) in poorer schools as expected.

Comment: @Bobson Yes, that would be a good way to count things.  In any case, I doubt that the data counts public school services, because that's sort of a universal thing that everyone has access to if they want.  I think the metrics would probably be limited to private purchases of goods and services.

Comment: I think "took a lot of labor to make" is a loose proxy for "expensive."  And it's not very groundbreaking to say that "rich people have a lot of expensive stuff and poor people don't."  Also, I deleted my answer, though it seems that comparing 2012 and 1956 is responsive to: "measure of inequality looks like in the US today **and in the recent past**".

Comment: @NL7 Well, I think the idea behind the measure isn't to focus on how much money rich people spend on goods and services, but rather to focus on the extent to which the rich are able to command the labor of the poor.  That is to say, to the extent that large numbers of people are expending all their labor serving a single person or a small number of people, that's considered a measure of inequality.

Comment: There is another issue, [capitalism has made everything vastly cheaper](http://myslu.stlawu.edu/~shorwitz/Good/myths.htm). So, when I am comparing th0e labor cost of an item from 1950, how do I take into account that the cost may be a fraction of that today?

Comment: There [have been some studies](http://www.iza.org/conference_files/EcCrRiUnEm2010/Meyer-Inequality1.4.pdf). In general, income inequality as a measure of wages is much greater than income inequality as a measure of consumption (which is mostly flat)

Comment: @user1873 But my question isn't about consumption inequality (which in any case is a flawed metric since the rich are more likely to save their money for future consumption or consumption by their heirs).  It's about the man-hours of the rest of us that goes into what the rich consume.

Comment: " I'm wondering about a different measure: the amount of labor, measured in man-hours, that is employed in the production of the goods and services that a given person consumes." **It isn't clear what you are asking.** Do you want a comparison of the yearly consumption of a "rich" person in 1900 versus a rich person in 2010? A rich 1900s consumption difference to a poor 1900s person versus their 2010 equivalents? The cost of production in man-hours of the goods consumed yearly by a rich 1900s person versus man-hours consumed yearly by a rich 2010s person? **Measuring man-hours isn't easy**

Comment: "but rather to focus on the extent to which the rich are able to command the labor of the poor. That is to say, to the extent that large numbers of people are expending all their labor serving a single person or a small number of people," That is an odd way to measure things. Say for example, you get your car fixed at a dealership that charges $90 an hour for a 3 hour job, but a rich person hires an expert on classic cars for $400 an hour for a 3-hoir job. Both rich and poor person have commanded 3-hours of work. There is no inequality between them.

Comment: @user1873  "It isn't clear what you are asking." I want to find out the difference, in any given year, between the number of man-hours that go into the goods and services consumed by a rich person compared to the number of man-hours that go into the goods and services of a poor person. I want to see how that disparity right now compares the disparity in the past, as well as how the disparity in the US now compares with the disparity in other countries.

Comment: "Measuring man-hours isn't easy."  Like I said, I'm not asking about some metric I made up.  I'm asking about something that's already been studied, and for which data presumably already exists.  So easy or not, people have at least attempted to measure the man-hours that go into the goods and services that various people consume.

Comment: "Both rich and poor person have commanded 3-hours of work. There is no inequality between them."  Yes, this isn't a perfect measure of all the effects of inequality.  Certainly rich people and poor people can have differences in the quality of goods and services.  But that's not what this metric is trying to capture.  It's trying to capture the extent to which society is unequal because all the work a person does, and all the work that a lot of his fellow workers do, is all being used to serve a single individual or a small number of individuals.

Comment: Is this a meaningful measure of inequality?  The sellers  of labor would prefer to be employed rather than not.

Comment: @NL7 Yes, it is a meaningful measure of inequality.  The question of whether this inequality should be removed, and if so how, is a completely separate matter.  Assuming that reducing this inequality is desirable, it's certainly conceivable that certain policies that might reduce it might have adverse side effects, like a butler who was working at a wealthy mansion not having that job anymore.  That's the efficiency vs. equity tradeoff.  But that has nothing to do with my question, which is purely about positive economics, not normative economics.

Comment: I just mean that it implies that if rich people were mostly serviced by a mass of robots that gave them lives of luxury with little or no human employment, and if poor people received all their food, clothing, and shelter from co-inhabitants at their subsistence kibbutzim, then the "wealth means other people's labor" metric would say that society was very unequal and that the inequality benefited the poor people.

Comment: @NL7 Yes, this isn't a perfect measure of inequality, and there are clearly cases in which it would misananalyze things according to our intuitive conception of inequality, but that's pretty much true of all measures of inequality.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan - But it's getting at the wrong relationship so it doesn't illuminate much.  The meaning of wealth is consumption, not labor.

Comment: Do you mean "metric of wealth? instead of "metric of inequality"

Comment: @SamIam No, it's not meant to measure wealth.  It's meant to measure how unequal society is, in terms of a large class of people expending all their labor in service of a single person or a small number of people. To the extent that it takes a lot of man-hours to make the goods and services that a person consumes, that indicates that they effectively have a lot of people working for them, so it's an indication of social stratification.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you looking for a scatter plot of wealth inequality vs. man-hours of work to produce the average yearly consumables of citizens by state? By country? Man-hours to produce the monthly consumables of the average citizen? Man-hours to produce durable goods? Which consumables? Which durable goods? For the average citizen of the given geographic region, or for the top 10% of the geographic region? Are you looking for something like a carbon footprint, but in man-hours? (This might be such a unique question it could win a Nobel prize in economics.)

Answer (score 4):

It appears that you've independently rediscovered a Smithian or Ricardian version of a labour theory of value.  In this mode of reasoning each hour of labour is equated with each other hour of labour.  Has difficulty explaining the movement of value from non-capitalised to capitalised industries and thus for differential profit.

Marx's category of "value," as in embodied crystalised realised socially necessary average productivity labour theory of value.  Marx's argument is in Capital, that prices will reflect the fluctuating value component, as expressed in average productivity socially necessary labour expended in their production.

While criticisms have been made of prices reflecting values ("The Transformation Problem"), these are still under continuous debate.  Begging the question on whether transformation is a problem or not, and whether if a problem answers have been supplied or not, we can use market prices to approximate underlying value.

Rich people buy more things, and more expensive things.  This would be your marker of a kind of stratification class.  1% vs the rest.  Marx wasn't satisfied with this.

However, the issue with using Marx for this is that Marx discovered empirically that not all labour hours are treated the same, and that the level of capitalisation (unit productivity per labour hour), personal productivity (length of the working day, fatigue), and social utility produced an "average" social labourer.  We could, for example, use CPI inflation as a time series reflecting what the bourgeoisie wish to pay the average social labourer and then do time series to work out the number of units of social labourer are consumed per rich person's wealth.  So it isn't an exact model: if domestic servants value productivity differs from (say) video game programmers, the price of the commodities they contribute to won't express the actual number of human hours of labour, but only the number of hours of human labour that our society (through market, production, class war) deems socially average.  (Marx argues this is why Sony is more profitable than a household cleaning firm: capitalisation productivity's affects on required hours of labour).

For Marx, class is best represented by how people control and relate to social production, not what their total volume of wealth is.  Wealth and class correlate strongly, but you get some useful results from relationship to production that aren't achieved in wealth analyses.  Like why first world workers go on strike.

Comment: If you think this answer is deficient, then please provide a comment so I can improve it.

Comment: I'm having a hard time following this answer.  It feels like it addresses the question, but I'm not sure.